# The crossword packing puzzle

Tags: packing

[image: the puzzle]

To describe it shortly, it's like Scrabble Tetris. Except the quality is much lower.

- Fit all the pieces inside the grid
- The pieces can NOT be rotated
- No piece can be placed on top of the crossed slots
- The letters must line up and create a valid crossword

Here's a text representation of the grid, where `o` is a valid place for a letter and `x` is not:

```
OOOOXOOXO  
OOXOOOOOO  
OOOOOXOOO  
OXOXOOOOO  
OOOOOXOOX  
XOOXOOOOO  
OOOOOOOOO  
XOXOOOXOO  
OOOOOOOOX
```

Comment: The text is very hard to read. I suggest moving the bullet points into the question, and maybe even trying to format everything else into the question, for screen readers and those that can't see images etc

Comment: Actually I [made an edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31319) to do some of this for you. Hopefully I got everything correct, but if not you are free to [edit] the question yourself.

Comment: I was very confused until I realized that:  
>! the number of letters is less than the number of empty spaces. You might want to specify that empty spaces are allowed...unless you want figuring that out to be part of the challenge!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Go ahead and take the [Tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn another badge. It looks like your question has an answer already. If the answer is acceptable, and it is unlikely a better answer could be made, then you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Agargara Ugh I never noticed that, I think that's sloppy. I was racking my brains try to solve it. I had a couple of the words but couldn't get them to fit because of that...They should've all just been filled with X's if they were meant to be empty, cause it's not a real crossword if it has gaps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note from /r/puzzles: The T in the top-right piece should be an I.

Solved:

> [image: solution]

Nice puzzle, thanks for posting!